# get rate with Ruby Money gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I'm using the  [Ruby Money gem (For rails)](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) for my app and i want to save the used currency rate for every order.

My base currency is USD and i give my users the option to pay in EUR, on a order save i want to record the used currency conversion rate.

I just can't find a method to get the used rate from this lib, anybody knows how to do this?

I'm also looking for best practice on this, for now i'm planning on saving the prices in order_lines in the users currency and save the used currency per line. As my original prices are in dollars i'm also saving the price in dollar per order line as reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will probably get better answers asking on the issues of the money-rails gem. The lead maintainer is very active there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example bank:

```
# config/initializers/money.rb
dev_bank = Money::Bank::VariableExchange.new
dev_bank.add_rate("EUR", "USD", 1.35)
dev_bank.add_rate("USD", "EUR", 1/1.35)
Money.default_bank = dev_bank
```

you can do this:

```
# somewhere else in your code
Money.default_bank.get_rate('EUR', 'USD')
```

See more info in the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/money/Money/Bank/VariableExchange#get_rate-instance_method)

Comment: from where did you get that 1.35? How could we possibly know that?

Comment: Wow, from a time where the rate was 1.35 :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're supposed to set up exchange rates in your configuration code using the [exchange bank object](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#currency-exchange) or the [`money.rb` initializer](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#configuration-parameters), in which case you already have access to the exchange rate in your code.

If for some reason you have access only to the input and output of the exchange conversion, you should be able to calculate the exchange rate yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if i calculate the rate myself it's a bit off because of the rounding in the Money gem. How would i get the config values from the money.rb initializer?

Comment: I'm kinda faking it here -- I have never used this gem -- but if money.rb is how the exchange rates are being set, then that file should be in your source code, maybe under config/initializers.